# MariaDB Won't Start After Installing

Tags: mariadb

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.4 server and I've recently removed mysql-server and mysql-client and am trying to get MariaDB up and running. I've installed both mariadb-server and mariadb-client. I stop and then try to restart maria db. I get the general error message:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I then run `systenctl status mariadb.service` and get the below:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.6.4 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-09-23 13:26:03 CDT; 8s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 97366 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 97377 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 97379 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   &&>
    Process: 97387 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 97387 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.6.4 database server...
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz sh[97384]: [114B blob data]
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz sh[97384]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz mariadbd[97387]: [106B blob data]
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz mariadbd[97387]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 13:26:03 notised.xyz systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.6.4 database server.
```

I've tried purging everything related to mysql and mariadb and reinstalled mariadb multiple times, but run into the same issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://askubuntu.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: include `journalctl -n 30 mariadb.service` too.

Comment: try to run `mariadb-install-db --user mysql --skip-test-db`

Comment: Please ignore or remove my last comment, I cant edit it anymore.

Try to run purge again: `sudo apt purge mariadb-server mariadb-common  mysql-common`
and install it again: `sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-common  mysql-common`

mysql-common is also important, it creates directory: /etc/mysql/conf.d

If it will not help try to run `mariadb-install-db --user mysql --skip-test-db`